# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a form where I have an HTML input that just takes numbers or letters.
The short form of my state interface is the following:

```
interface State {
    location: string;
    startDate: Date;
}
```

I initialize my state like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        location: '',
        startDate: new Date(),
    });
```

My onChangeHandler is the following:

```
const handleChangeLocation = useCallback((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        setState(prevState =>
            update(prevState, {
                location: {$set: event.target.value},
            })
        );
    }, []);
```

The HTML input is this:

```
<input id="search-grid-location" className="search-grid-element" type="text"
                           placeholder="Location"
                           onChange={handleChangeLocation}/>
```

When I write i. e. 1 in the input there is no error but when I write 2, after the first input, the error occurs. The input field contains 12

The error occurs at the location line. See the [image: picture]

I debugged the application and the event.target.value holds the input values. So there might be an error with the prevState variable. I use functional components.

I use to update my state the immutability-helper package. [Link](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

Comment: Are you sure that `event` and `event.target` contain values? Error sounds like `event.target` is `null`

Comment: Yes the values aren't null. Robbies solution worked and it makes absolutely sense. Double checked the event.target.value

Answer (score 14):

Before you call `setState` you're going to want to grab the value of `event.target.value`. By the time `setState` is executed (especially since you're using functional setState), the React SyntheticEvent will have been cleared, so it's target property will be null.

```
useCallback((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  // do this and your error will go away
  const {value} = event.target;
  setState(prevState =>
    update(prevState, {
      location: {$set: value},
    })
  );
}, []);
```

read more about the [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: I had the same exact problem. calling setState() directly from onChange() and it worked on 95% of the fields until it failed on 1 field. I guess I've must have been lucky with the other ones :)